# How to remove duplicate elements from an array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array objects with keys `path` and `current`. How to remove duplicate elements, where key `current` has the same value.

```js
let arrPath = [{
  path: [1, 2],
  current: "K"
}, {
  path: [0, 3],
  current: "I"
}, {
  path: [1, 3],
  current: "N"
}, {
  path: [1, 4],
  current: "N"
}, {
  path: [0, 2],
  current: "G"
}, {
  path: [2, 2],
  current: "G"
} ];
```

Comment: From dupe: `arrPath = arrPath.filter((item, index, self) => self.findIndex(t => t.current === item.current) === index)`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

You can remove duplicate objects (duplicate object in the sense that it contains duplicate `current` property) by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
let arrPath = [{ path: [1, 2], current: "K" }, { path: [0, 3], current: "I" }, { path: [1, 3], current: "N" }, { path: [1, 4], current: "N" }, { path: [0, 2], current: "G" }, { path: [2, 2], current: "G" }]

let resultData = arrPath.reduce((elements, obj, index) => {
  let existingData = elements.find(element =>
    element.current === obj.current
  );
  if (!existingData) {
    elements.push(obj);
  }
  return elements;
}, []);

console.log(resultData)
```

Comment: Reduce instead of filter?. Also a massive dupe. Here is a version from the dupe I chose to close the question with `arrPath = arrPath.filter((item, index, self) => self.findIndex(t => t.current === item.current) === index)`

Comment: A neater reduce also from the dupe: `Object.values(arrPath.reduce((acc,cur)=>Object.assign(acc,{[cur.current]:cur}),{}))`

Answer (score -2):

You can map each value in the array to an entry using the `current` values for the keys.

Then use these entries to construct a `Map` object, effectively eliminating duplicate entries.

You can convert the `Map` back to an array using `Array.from`

```js
Array.from(new Map(arrPath.map(o => [o.current, o])).values())
```